# Angular check if particular route path in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, router

`http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/#message` and if I type in the URL (remove #message and type application-management)
`http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/application-management` (/application-management), it should redirect me to `http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/#/application-management`. For any other route stay on `http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/#message`.

How can i achieve this using angular?

Comment: can you please ask your question more specifically. Like It might take some more space, but community will understand it better and will try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you want to add dynamic routing in your project ?
Or If you want to redirect you system if url is not existing in your system
then find below code

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "/yourdefaultcomponent" },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
```

Comment: So basically the concept is if some flag is false I'm showing this component so basically routing to http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/#message (kind of maintenance page) so none of the url should be accessible except  http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/application-management, therefore I can directly type this url in address bar and navigate to this page (admin kind of page) where I can turn flag to true and application is up and running, hence I wwanted to navigate this url by typing the /application-management

Comment: Yes you should default page ,error page,or blank page then it will redirect you that component

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new route in your Routes array in your router module, e.g.:

```
{ path: '/application-management', redirectTo: '/message', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Comment: If I'm in http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/#message it should redirect me to the URL http://localhost:4200/dsc-ui/#/application-management. Also, I'm using Hash Strategy I'm not sure how your answer will fulfill my requirement

Comment: Then I would suggest to add that to the question.